# How to add command line args to java systemd service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu

How can I add command line arguments correctly to a java systemd service? In the following example, `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` is not taken into account. Thus the location is maybe wrong?

```
[Unit]
Description=Manage Java service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/prod
ExecStart=/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -jar myapp.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test
User=java
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Have you tried to set spring profile argument first. `java -Dspring.profiles.active=test`

Answer (score 1):

`myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=test`